# d3 Bar chart with a tool tip is not working

Tags: javascript, json, django, d3.js, svg

I've been working with a D3 svg chart with built in tool tips (using the d3-tip library). The original code can be seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

I am using Django as back end and I am trying to populate log count as per year from datetime. I was successfully able to populate the axis and labels of the graph except the bars.

Here is my html template called `graph.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z").parse;  // for dates like "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Log Count:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.count_items + "</span>";
  })


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("{% url "log_count_by_year" %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year = parseDate(d.year);
    d.count_items = +d.count_items;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count_items; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -38)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Log count");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.count_items); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.count_items); })
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In `views.py` I wrote this code to successfully find the count as per year:

```
def graph(request):
    return render(request, 'graph/graph.html')

def log_count_by_year(request):
    data = log_runs.objects.all() \
        .extra(select={'year': connections[log_runs.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('year', 'RUN_DATETIME')}) \
        .values('year') \
        .annotate(count_items=Count('ID'))
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

I am successfully able to get the JSON object when I do the api call, here is the JSON object that I got:

```
[{"count_items": 22, "year": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 16, "year": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 16, "year": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 6, "year": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 2, "year": "2011-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 2, "year": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2008-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2007-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 2, "year": "2006-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2005-01-01T00:00:00Z"}, {"count_items": 1, "year": "2004-01-01T00:00:00Z"}]
```

But in the front end I am only able to see the axes and the labels and no bar graphs:[Front end visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBmQC.png)
Except the bars and the tool tip everything works fine. Can someone help me out on whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is simple: a time scale has no `rangeBand()`.

As you have the years as a **categorical** variable, and not a quantitative variable (after all, this is a bar chart, not a line chart), I suggest you simply change your scale for an ordinal one:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);
```

After that, drop your parser and change your domain accordingly:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.year;
}));
```

Finally, don't forget to call the tooltip:

```
svg.call(tip);
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```html
<style>
  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
  .bar {
    fill: orange;
  }
  
  .bar:hover {
    fill: orangered;
  }
  
  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .d3-tip {
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
  
  .d3-tip:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* Style northward tooltips differently */
  
  .d3-tip.n:after {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }

</style>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 40,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .rangeBands([0, width], 0.2);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Log Count:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.count_items + "</span>";
      })


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
      svg.call(tip);

    var data = [{
      "count_items": 22,
      "year": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 16,
      "year": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 16,
      "year": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 6,
      "year": "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2013-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2012-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 2,
      "year": "2011-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 2,
      "year": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2008-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2007-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 2,
      "year": "2006-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2005-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }, {
      "count_items": 1,
      "year": "2004-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }];

    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = d.year.split("-")[0];
      d.count_items = +d.count_items;
    });

    x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.year;
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.count_items;
    })]);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -38)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Log count");

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.year);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.count_items);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.count_items);
      })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

  </script>
```